# Row and column wise data insertion using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Below are the two input dataframe df1 and df2

```
df1
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    A1  A2  A3  Total
Sam      a+b    p+q    50   25  25   4
Joy      a+b    r+s    0    25  75   4
Roy      c+d    p+q    33.3 0   66.7 3

df2
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    B1  B2  B3  Total
Sam     a+b     p+q     0   0   4    4
Joy     a+b     r+s     1   0   3    4
Roy     c+d     p+q     0   0   3    3
```

Values of A1,A2,A3 from df1 should be filled by looking non zero values of B1,B2,B3 of df2.
The intended output is:

```
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3    A1B1    A1B2    A1B3    A2B1    A2B2    A2B3    A2B3    A3B1    A3B2 A3B3
Sam     a+b     p+q      0       0       50      0       0       25     0        0      0   25
Joy     a+b     r+s      0       0        0      25      0       0      0        0      0   75
Roy     c+d     p+q      0       0      33.3     0       0       0      0        0      0   66.7
```

Comment: What are the rules for the intended output?

Comment: Values of A1,A2,A3 from df1 should be filled by looking non zero values of B1,B2,B3 of df2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tmp = [(a, df2.filter(like='B').astype(bool).mul(df1[a], axis=0)) for a in df1.filter(like='A').columns]
new_df = pd.concat([x.set_axis(a + x.columns, axis=1) for a, x in tmp], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   A1B1  A1B2  A1B3  A2B1  A2B2  A2B3  A3B1  A3B2  A3B3
0   0.0   0.0  50.0     0     0    25   0.0   0.0  25.0
1   0.0   0.0   0.0    25     0    25  75.0   0.0  75.0
2   0.0   0.0  33.3     0     0     0   0.0   0.0  66.7
```